# wordpress - how to hyperlink from post to another

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I want to redirect users from one post to another by clicking the hyperlink in the current post in Wordpress. What I did is marking the text I want and clicked on hyperlink icon but there was no options there to select the page or post I wanted. It's just an input field which should be filled manually by typing!

Where can I find pages/posts to select? Do I need any plugin to be installed?

Comment: You can just start typing the post/page title in that box and the post/page list below will be filtered depending on your search term. Then you can select what post/page to choose for hyperlinking.

Comment: thank you dear @Junaid but no result fetched :( doesn't it have problems with arabic letters?